# Referencing a routine parameter when there are table columns in scope with the same name

Tags: hsqldb

Let's say I have a table named `"People"` with two columns `"FirstName"` and `"LastName"`, and the following function which references that table (this is a contrived and simplified example with the sole purpose of illustrating my problem):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION PUBLIC."SelectPeopleByFirstName" (
    IN "FirstName" VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE (
      "FirstName" VARCHAR(100)
    , "LastName" VARCHAR(100)
)
READS SQL DATA
RETURN TABLE (
    SELECT
          "People"."FirstName"
        , "People"."LastName"
    FROM
        PUBLIC."People"
    WHERE
        "People"."FirstName" = "FirstName"
)
```

The problem is that, in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement, the identifier `"FirstName"` is treated as a reference to the table column `"People"."FirstName"` instead of the routine parameter `"FirstName"`.

Now, Google tells me that I am not the first one to encounter this problem, and from the different suggested solutions that I could find, the one that I found most satisfactory was to qualify the identifier with the routine name, like this:

```sql
WHERE
    "People"."FirstName" = "SelectPeopleByFirstName"."FirstName"
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to work with HSQLDB, because I am getting the following error:

> user lacks privilege or object not found: SelectPeopleByFirstName.FirstName / Error Code: -5501 / State: 42501

Of course, I could give the routine parameter a different, distinct name, but I would consider this more of a workaround than a solution, because then the functionality of the routine would be contingent on the table "People" not containing a column with a name identical to that of the routine parameter, which is something that can change without the routine knowing about it.

So am I doing/understanding something wrong here, or am I really forced to resort to crude workarounds in order to solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use distinct names for variables. Users typically use a naming convention for parameters, shown in this example from HSQLDB Guide with `_P` appended to names.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc(INOUT val_p INT, IN lastname_p VARCHAR(20)) 
 MODIFIES SQL DATA
 BEGIN ATOMIC
   SET val_p = 0;
   for_label: FOR SELECT * FROM customer WHERE lastname = lastname_p DO
     IF  val_p > 0 THEN
       DELETE FROM customer WHERE customer.id = id;
     END IF;
     SET val_p = val_p + 1;
   END FOR for_label;
 END
```

And HSQLDB does not allow you to rename a table column that is used in a routine, so it cannot go wrong with later changes.

Comment: It's true that HSQLDB does not allow renaming a table column that is used in a routine, but in your example, it's still possible to add a column named `lastname_p` to the table `customer` after the routine has been created, which will render the routine broken. Granted, the odds of this happening unintentionally are rather low, but still, the fact that the responsibility to prevent this lies with the programmer instead of the database engine makes this a workaround and not a solution, in my opinion. However, I came up with something myself, which I'm going to post as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

After learning from fredt's answer that it is not possible to qualify the parameter name, I came up with a not terribly elegant construct that nevertheless solves the problem I addressed in the question. Instead of populating the return table by selecting directly from the `"People"` table which can have any number of columns with arbitrary names that the routine does not know about, I create a subquery acting as a "pipeline" to the `"People"` table and select from this subquery:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION PUBLIC."SelectPeopleByFirstName" (
    IN "FirstName_Param" VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE (
      "FirstName" VARCHAR(100)
    , "LastName" VARCHAR(100)
)
READS SQL DATA
RETURN TABLE (
    SELECT
          "FirstName"
        , "LastName"
    FROM (  
        SELECT
              "FirstName"
            , "LastName"
        FROM
            PUBLIC."People"
    )
    WHERE
        "FirstName" = "FirstName_Param"
)
```

Now, the identifier `"FirstName_Param"` in the `WHERE` clause will always refer to the routine parameter, even if, for some unfathomable reason, someone adds a column named `"FirstName_Param"` to the table `"People"`, because the the table `"People"` is out of scope in the `WHERE` clause.